# Can we use magento extension in existing php website

Tags: php, magento

I am new to Magento development ,

And i am wondering if i could use Magento Extension in my existing php site ? or is it mandetory to have magento site for using magento extension ?

Comment: I literally have no idea as you've not given us any information. Speculatively though I'd imagine no, not without the base system. Please edit your question to give some more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento Extensions are solely plugins for Magento, so Magento is necessary.